# error LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol __std_max_element_1 when using llvm from vcpkg

Tags: c++, linker, llvm, std

I just installed llvm 17.0.2#1 using vcpkg, the build went fine but now when I try to use it I get this linker error :
`LLVMCore.lib(DataLayout.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_max_element_1 referenced in function "unsigned char const * __cdecl __std_max_element<unsigned char const >(unsigned char const *,unsigned char const *)" (??$__std_max_element@$$CBE@@YAPEBEPEBE0@Z)`

The project is a newly-created Visual Studio 2022 c++ empty project, with `_SILENCE_ALL_CXX23_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` defined to allow compilation (otherwise I get a deprecated feature compile error in c++23)

Here is my source file :

```
#pragma warning(disable:4146)
#include <llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>


int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<llvm::LLVMContext> TheContext;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile in c++14/17/20 and 23/newest, I get the same error every time.

Some more info:

- Windows SDK : 10.0
- Platform toolset : Visual Studio 2022 (v143)
- vcpkg AutoLink is set to True
- I have other packages from vcpkg that work

Answer (score 0):

Updating Visual Studio fixed it